# Where's my pointer error?

Tags: c, realloc

I've walked through the following code, but I can't find what's wrong.  The function `getsxnremem()` gets a string up to `len` chars using `fgets()`, overwrites the newline (if there is one) with a null-terminator, then re-sizes the memory to fit the string. That's the idea anyway.

The following code sometimes works and sometimes crashes.  I've had this happen plenty of times in the past and I usually find the problem, but this time it's taking me too long.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned getsxnremem(char **str, unsigned len){
    unsigned l, flag = 1;
    free(*str);
    char *buff;
    if ((*str = malloc(len)) == NULL) return 0;
    if(fgets(*str, len, stdin) == NULL) { free(*str); return 0; }
    l = strlen(*str);
    if (l && ((*str)[l-1] == '\n')) { *(str)[l-1] = '\0'; flag = 0; }
    if ((buff = realloc(*str, l + flag)) == NULL){ free(*str); return 0; }
    *str = buff;
    return (l - 1);
}


int main(void){
    char *buff = NULL;
    unsigned l = getsxnremem(&buff, 256);
    printf("%s\n%u chars long.", buff, l);
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value from `fgets()`.  If it gets EOF, there might not be a valid string to run `strlen()` on — the memory returned by `malloc()` is not guaranteed to be a null-terminated string.  That's a refinement over and above the problem with not collecting the return value from `realloc()`, though it would be an unusual implementation that relocated an allocation when the space being used was shrunk.

Comment: if the string doesn't end in a new line, you realloc to its string-length. That is 1 byte short for the null-terminator, will return the wrong length, and the printf might read past the allocated memory and output garbage! Add `else ++l;` to fix

Comment: @king_nak You're right.  I updated the code to deal with this.  The main error still exists though.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks.  I've updated the code to check the return value of fgets() and to use the return value of realloc().  Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your most recent update, you've got your parenthesis in the wrong place.

This:

```
if (l && ((*str)[l-1] == '\n')) { *(str)[l-1] = '\0'; flag = 0; }
```

Should be:

```
if (l && ((*str)[l-1] == '\n')) { (*str)[l-1] = '\0'; flag = 0; }
                                   ^---- here
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is, you failed to collect the return value of `realloc()` there.

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §7.22.3.5

> `#include <stdlib.h>`
>   `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);`
>
> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. [...]

`realloc()` resizes the memory and *returns* a pointer to the new memory. The old memory is to be `free()`d, considering `realloc()` is successful.

So,

1. You need to collect and check the return value of `realloc()` and test it against NULL to ensure success. Then, reassign it to `*str`.

   *NOTE: Please **do not** use a form like `p = realloc(p, newsize);` because, then, if `realloc()` fails, you'll end up losing the actual pointer, too.*
2. If `realloc()` is successful, you must not `free()` the *old* pointer. Calling `free()` on already `free()`-d memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that, as rightly mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35345517/2173917) by [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush), the usage

```
 { *(str)[l-1] = '\0'; flag = 0; }
```

is also wrong. Your required *string* is represented by `*str`, not `str`. As per the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), The   Array subscripting operator (`[]`) has higher precedence over the dereference (`*`) operator, so essentially your code looks like

```
{ * ((str)[l-1]) = '\0'; flag = 0; }
```

Which is not what you want. So, to honor the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), you should modify it like

```
{ (*str)[l-1] = '\0'; flag = 0; }
```

That said, you should also check for the return value of `fgets()` to ensure the success before you make use of the destination buffer. As `malloc()` returns unitialized memory, and in case `fgets()` fails, you'll end up reading from unitialized memory which will again cause UB.

Comment: It may seem trivial, but "resizing" potentially involves _moving_ the allocation.  Mentioning the idea of movement may help the OP understand and visualize why different addresses are involved.

Comment: I've updated the code with your suggestions: now I assign the return value of realloc() to the string if the realloc was successful.  I also added a check on the return value of fgets().  Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: @KorganRivera I've updated my answer to address the issue. Thanks to dbush, too. :)